# Update Kotlin StateFlow without change emitting

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

Is it possible to update Kotlin StateFlow without emitting the change?
The use case is that when user zooms a chart view, I would like to have that restored when activity resumes but skip the StateFlow events while zooming is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Although it may lead to obscure bugs.

On a `StateFlow<T>` you can get the latest known value (bear in mind that it might not exist). Since Kotlin (like java) **uses references for objects** (it might not work for primitive types) then you may apply modifications to returned object from `yourState.value`.

Comment: A StateFlow always has a value., so it's incorrect to say it might not exist.

Comment: True. I got confused with `MutableStateFlow`

Comment: MutableStateFlow, being a subtype of StateFlow, always has a value as well. You might be thinking of LiveData on Android.

Comment: That, precisely

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the latest state only when your Activity resumes, then don't `collect` the flow. You can get the latest value from the `StateFlow.value` property in `Activity.onResume()`. But then again, then you don't need a Flow in the first place and can simply use a property that directly stores the value you want.

Comment: This does not work well because when an activty is resumed the data gets loaded into the chart `asyncronously` and `onResume` may get called prior to data is loaded causing to zoom action make no effect.

Comment: Then check the value when the data arrives.